# Is there a way to Expand-Archive without overwriting files?

Tags: powershell

Is there a way in PowerShell to use `Expand-Archive` so that files are written where they don't exist, but are not overwritten when they do exist?  I can achieve this with `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`, but that ignores things that might be actual errors.

Comment: You would need to code it yourself most likely. You can use the ZipArchive .NET class for this. If you are to give this a go and have issues with your code, update your question with what you currently have

Comment: I think it would be much easier to just silence the output, and send the errors to your own variable using `-ErrorVariable` and parse it after if you're concerned about "actual" errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To silence only "file already exists" error messages of `Expand-Archive`, you can redirect the error stream to the success stream and process error records using `ForEach-Object`:

```sh
Expand-Archive -Path Test.zip -DestinationPath . -EA Continue 2>&1 | ForEach-Object {
   if( $_ -is [System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord] ) {
        if( $_.FullyQualifiedErrorId -split ',' -notcontains 'ExpandArchiveFileExists' ) {
            Write-Error $_   # output error that is not "file exists"
        }
   } 
   else {
       $_  # pass success stream through
   }
}
```

- `-EA Continue` (`-ErrorAction`) overrides the preference variable `$ErrorActionPreference` to make sure errors are not turned into exceptions (in which case the first error would interrupt the extraction).
- `2>&1` [redirects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-7.2) (merges) the error stream (#2) to the success stream  (#1), so both can be processed using `ForEach-Object`.
- `$_ -is [System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]` tests if the current pipeline element is an [error record](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.errorrecord?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0).

  - When this is the case, we test what kind of error we have, by checking the `FullyQualifiedErrorId` property of the `ErrorRecord` (the exception type `System.IO.IOException` would be too general to test for)
  - Otherwise it is a message from the success stream, which will be simply passed through.
- In case you are wondering how I came up with that `FullyQualifiedErrorId` thing, I just run `Expand-Archive` without redirection and called `Get-Error` afterwards. This outputs all information of the last error record, so I could look up the information to detect the error condition.

---

An alternative solution, similar to the one suggested by [Abraham Zinala](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14903754/abraham-zinala), is to unconditionally silence all errors and use `-ErrorVariable` to collect the errors and shown the relevant ones after the call to `Expand-Archive` has returned:

```sh
$oldErrorActionPreference = $ErrorActionPreference
$ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
$archiveErrors = $null

Expand-Archive -Path Test.zip -DestinationPath . -ErrorVariable archiveErrors

$ErrorActionPreference = $oldErrorActionPreference

$archiveErrors | Sort-Object { $_ | Out-String } -Unique | ForEach-Object {
    if( $_ -is [System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord] ) {
        if( $_.FullyQualifiedErrorId -split ',' -notcontains 'ExpandArchiveFileExists' ) {
            $_   # output error that is not "file exists"
        }
    }
}
```

- The errors of `Expand-Archive` cannot be completely silenced through the `-ErrorAction` parameter, because some errors (like input file doesn't exist) are detected as part of parameter validation. To really silence all errors, the `$ErrorActionPreference` variable must be used.
- It is important to set the error variable to `$null` before calling `Expand-Archive` because the command doesn't reset the variable, when there is no error.
- The name of the variable passed to `-ErrorVariable` must be specified **without** `$`.
- The `Sort-Object -Unique` command makes sure we don't show duplicate errors.